# Background compile in VS2010 and C/C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I use `Visual Studio 2010` and Intel `icc` compiler for `C` development. I use `C99` but editor is still showing `C99` constructs as errors (compiling is fine). How to get rid of it?

Second question, is it possible to use `Eclipse` (CDT) with Intel compiler on Windows?

Comment: are you compiling in c99 mode?

Comment: Yes, build (compile) runs smoothly. But some fake error is indicated.

Comment: I think he's having a problem with intellisense.

Comment: Intellisense sucks anyway (and doesn't do background compile). And Microsoft doesn't want to know about C99, so basically you're screwed.

Comment: @Alexandre C. On VS2010 Intellisense uses the EDG frontend to do a sort of background compilation. It doesn't produce executable code, but compiles the source to some sort of intermediate binary contained in the `ipch` file.

Comment: @Preatorian: It doesn't use the same compiler/parser/analyser/whatever than for compilation, so it's not background compile *à la* VB. Their buying of the EDG frontend was an horrible (half working actually) hack to meet deadlines. Anyway, you're stuck with the subset of C99 EDG understands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the responses to your post, the problem you're seeing is with your intellisense only.

You can turn off intellisense error reporting in VS2010:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced. Under IntelliSense, choose "Disable Error Reporting" and set it to "True".